# Disable Copy&paste through Clipboard functions in Android by using Xposed

Tags: java, android, clipboardmanager, xposed, xposed-framework

I am currently developing an app(API level 23) that is going to allow the user to choose what application will have the copy and paste functionality enabled. I am working with Xposed to do so.

I have 2 files at the moment. MainActivity.java and Main.java and
my code is error free but does not work for some reasons. After extensive research, I chose to modify the behavior of SetPrimaryClip and GetPrimaryClip as follows:

**Modified SetPrimaryClip in Main.java:**

```
if (isBlackListed())
{
    //if app checked

    //TO DO: Add block copy and paste functionality for UI

    //Here the context is passing
    ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
    clipBoard.setPrimaryClip(data);


    Toast.makeText(c, "Hack Enabled for copy func", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //debug hack enabled
    XposedBridge.log(" hack enabled for copy func");
    XposedBridge.log(packName);
    log_call(", hack enabled for copy func");


} else {
    //if app not checked
    Toast.makeText(c, "Hack disabled for copy func", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //debug hack disabled
    XposedBridge.log(" hack disabled for copy func");
    XposedBridge.log(packName);
    log_call(", hack disabled for copy func");

}
```

**Modified GetPrimaryClip in Main.java:**

```
if (isBlackListed())
{
    ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


    ClipData cp = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip();
    ClipData.Item item = cp.getItemAt(0);
    String text = item.getText().toString(); text=null;


    //if app not checked
    Toast.makeText(c, "Hack enabled for paste func", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //debug hack disabled
    XposedBridge.log("hack enabled for paste func");
    XposedBridge.log(packName);
    log_call(", hack enabled for paste func");


    param.setResult(null);

} else {



    //if app not checked
    Toast.makeText(c, "Hack disabled for paste func", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //debug hack disabled
    XposedBridge.log("hack disabled for paste func");
    XposedBridge.log(packName);
    log_call(", hack disabled for paste func");


}
```

Note that I don't have any compilation errors at all. Am I hooking the wrong methods here?